# How to set relationship when I create a new (custom) content to another (custom) content in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, content-type, relationship

Premise: I'm new in the world of Drupal, so sorry if this is a stupid question.

What I need is to set some relationships for some new content types I created. For example, I created the "Person" content type and the "Group" content type. Using the "Relation" module I have defined the relation "is in", but now if I want to add a field for setting the relation at creation time, there are no edit widget available. The only way I found to set relationships is using the entity collector: too complicated for a user.

Example: a user creates the  Person "John", and he want for him to set the relation "is in" with the Group "Drupal fans". So, during the creation of this Person he needs, for example, a select control that lets him to choose from all the groups already registered in the site.

In brief, I need to manage some entities created by me, with CRUD controls, list, etc. and I need to set some relationships from these entities.

What is the best method/ what are the best module/ how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the references module: http://drupal.org/project/references

Comment: References will most probably be deprecated in the near future in favor of [Entity Reference](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference), which should probably be considered first on fresh D7 projects.

Comment: I've had a lot of problems using Entity Reference so I didn't recommend it, though in fairness it's been a few months.

Comment: In the next days I will test E.R. and I will give my opinion! Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

You can create an taxanomy list of your'e groups at Structure -> Taxonomy.
This list you can use in creating an field. By the creation of the field choose for "Term reference" type and then "Autocomplete term widget". Click on save and choose the Taxonomy list that you created.
Hope this is what you need!